# Is there anyway to remove the shadow, or force vuetify menu to fully align with the left side of the screen?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use vuetify menu in a sidebar navigation. I would like for the menu to align perfectly to the left side of the screen. Instead what I am getting is the menu is insisting to be positioned 12px away from the edge of my screen and wrecking my alignment.

Is there a way to disable the shadow or to force the alignment? The left: 12px is specified directly on the element's style so CSS has no effect.

I have tried this but no luck:

```
<v-menu offset-y nudge-left="-12" flat>
```

https://codepen.io/RuttyJ/pen/BevNmy?editors=1010

Any ideas?

Update:
Made some progress:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBLMob

This achieves the effect but requires the override of the menu nudge on a global level to 0px !important.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `content-class` like:

```
<v-menu content-class="elevation-0">
```

Comment: Nice solution :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `elevation` directive to remove the shadow.

Just add `elevation="0"` to your element.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/elevation

Answer (score 2):

To remove the shadow, you could simply override the styles for `.v-menu__content`. In some CSS:

```
.v-menu__content {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Aligning to the left can be done setting the styles via javascript.

Having said that, I think it is easier to make a sidebar menu from scratch than trying to transform a component which is not meant to be a sidebar into one. Transitions will be off, and so much on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$menu-content-elevation: 0;`.

[SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)

[Available menu component SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#sass-menu-content-elevation)

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue but with a menu activator less than `12px` from the top of the page.

Looking at the source for the `VMenu` component (via the menuable mixin) you can see that `12px` is a hard coded minimum distance. The only way I can see to get around this is to `!important` override the css only for these specific cases.

[Left calculation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/menuable/index.ts#L201): `left = Math.max(left, 12);`
[Top calculation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/menuable/index.ts#L231): `return top < 12 ? 12 : top;`

I have created a [Vuetify Issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11818) to cover the `top` case.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with a v-navigation-drawer component Vuetify 2.0

`<v-menu class="elevation-0" >`

Answer (score 0):

vuetify 3.0

```
<v-menu>
 ...code
 <v-list class="elevation-0"> // <- this code use.
   ...code
 </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

v-menu props not working , v-list use success